# Ocultar columna en JTable JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

Uso la tabla de Jquery JTable, y quiero saber como se oculta la columna:

Tabla:

```
$('#miTabla').jtable({
    title : 'Datos Detalle',
    paging : true,
    pageSize : 10,
    pageList : 'minimal',
    saveUserPreferences : true,
    jqueryuiTheme: true,
    messages : {
        noDataAvailable: 'No hay datos disponibles!',
        addNewRecord: 'Añade detalle',
        editRecord: 'Edita detalle',
        save: 'Guardar'

    },
    actions : {
        listAction: 'listDetailAction'
    },
    fields : { 
        idDetalle : {
            title : "Id Detalle",
            key : true,
            list : false
        },
        detalle : {
            title : 'Concepto',
            width: '33%'

        },
        descripcion : {
            title : 'Descripción',
            width: '33%'
        }
    }
});
```

Segun la [documentacion oficial](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Methods#met-changeColumnVisibility): Existe el método `changeColumnVisibility(columnName, visibility)`, pero no sé como se usa.

He probado lo siguiente:

```
$('#miTabla').jtable('changeColumnVisibility',{detalle :'hidden'});
```

Pero no hace nada, ni error ni ninguna información útil.

**¿Alguien conoce cual puede ser mi error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No haga así

> $('#miTabla').jtable('changeColumnVisibility',{detalle :'hidden'});

Cambie a esto

`$('#miTabla').jtable('changeColumnVisibility','detalle','hidden');`

**Documentación**

http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Methods#met-changeColumnVisibility

Answer (score 1):

Intenta colocando **visibility** en uno de tus campos, ademas antes de `fields` te falta una coma (**,**) y todos los `fields` deben estar dentro de llaves `{}`

```
$('#miTabla').jtable({
    title : 'Datos Detalle',
    paging : true,
    pageSize : 10,
    pageList : 'minimal',
    saveUserPreferences : true,
    jqueryuiTheme: true,
    messages : {
        noDataAvailable: 'No hay datos disponibles!',
        addNewRecord: 'Añade detalle',
        editRecord: 'Edita detalle',
        save: 'Guardar'

    },
    actions : {
        listAction: 'listDetailAction'
    }, //te falta esta coma
    fields : { //te falta esta llave
        idDetalle : {
            title : "Id Detalle",
            key : true,
            list : false
        },
        detalle : {
            title : 'Concepto',
            width: '33%'
            visibility: 'hidden' //propiedad para ocultar
        },
        descripcion : {
            title : 'Descripción',
            width: '33%'
        }
     }//te falta esta llave

});
```

Comment: Pedro Gonzalez Rojas Acabo de probarlo y no funciona